# boost threadpool with a thread that handles an IO queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I recently began experimenting with the [pseudo-boost threadpool](http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/) (pseudo because it hasn't been officially accepted yet).

As a simple exercise, I initialized the **threadpool with a maximum of two threads**.

Each task does two things:

- a CPU-intensive calculation
- writes out the result to disk

#### Question

How do I modify the model into a **threadpool** that does:

- a CPU-intensive calculation

and a **single I/O thread** which listens for completion from the threadpool - takes the resultant memory and simply:

- writes out the result to disk

> Should I simply have the task communicate to the I/O thread (spawned
>   as std::thread) through a std::condition_variable (essentially a mutexed queue of calculation results) or is there a way to
>   do it all within the threadpool library?
>
> Or is the gcc 4.6.1 implementation of `future` and `promise` mature enough for me to pull this off?

### Answer

It looks like a simple [mutex queue with a condition variable](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html) works fine.

By grouping read access and writes, in addition to using the threadpool, I got the following improvements:

- 2 core machine: 1h14m down to 33m (46% reduction in runtime)
- 4 core vm: 40m down to 18m (55% reduction in runtime)

Thanks to **Martin James** for his thoughtful answer.  Before this exercise, I thought that my next computational server should have dual-processors and a ton of memory.  But now, with so much processing power inherent in the multiple cores and hyperthreading, I realize that money will probably better spent dealing with the I/O bottleneck.

As Martin mentioned, having multiple drives or RAID configurations would probably help.  I will also look into adjusting I/O buffer settings at the kernel level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is only one local disk, one writer thread on the end of a producer-consumer queue would be my favourite. Seeks, networked-disk delays and other hiccups will not leave any pooled threads that have finsihed their calculation stuck trying to write to the disk.  Other disk operations, (eg. select another location/file/folder), are also easier/quicker if only one thread is accessing it - the queue will take up the slack and allow seamless calculation during the latency.

Writing directly from the calcualtion task or submitting the result-write as a separate task would work OK but you would need more threads in the pool to achieve pause-free operation.

Everything changes if there is more than one disk.  More than one writer thread would then become a worthwhile proposition because of the increased overall performance.  I would then probably go with an array/list of queues/write-threads, one for each disk.